# How to deploy to elastic beanstalk from Jenkins Blue Ocean?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jenkins-blueocean

How would I integrate the [awseb deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin) on Jenkins into a declarative pipeline on Jenkins blue ocean? I am looking for an example of a pipeline step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using the code here as a template: https://github.com/hypothesis/deployment/blob/master/Jenkinsfile.